# TFS version control - File deleted, added - how do we tell TFS it was a move?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, refactoring, resharper

We are doing some major refactoring and in the course of that we are moving a lot of files. We use ReSharper which makes this (relatively) painless as it updates all uses everywhere when we move files - even to a different project. So everything is great.

Except we just discovered today that ReSharper would tell TFS to delete the file in the old location and then insert as a new file in the new location. How can we tell TFS that this delete/insert was actually a move?

Comment: Resharper 9 is out ... what are the chances this bug is fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**:  You don't.

**Long Answer**: You don't unless you want to run the possibility of completely hosing your source control.

From the perspective of TFS, the file in the new location is a completely different file.  It even has a different ID in the database server.

Now you could certainly go spelunking in your TFS database and try to manually update the file id associations.  But this has an extremely high probability of completely screwing yourself... unless you were one of the main developers of TFS that was intimately familiar with the backend of the product.  In which case you wouldn't be asking this question. ;)

Slightly off-topic item: You should contact jetbrains and tell them to fix this.

Comment: {inappropiate swear word} - this is not good. If we'd known what ReSharper was doing we could have used it to cause all the edits, then copy the files elsewhere, undo the checkout, move the files, check them out, then copy back. But we learned this afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, we're thinking of doing that.

Comment: @Resharper, you guys fixing this??

Comment: For anyone else wondering: Here's the related Resharper Bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-179384

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar situation where I wanted to move files between projects and I wanted to have Resharper do as much work as possible. Here are the steps I ended up doing:

1. Move the file in Resharper. This will make the appropriate change to the target project file.
2. Close the solution or disable Resharper.
3. Undo the delete/add in TFS.
4. Move the file in TFS.
5. Make sure that the moved file is no longer in the source project.
6. Reload the solution or re-enable Resharper.
7. Use Resharper to make any namespace changes.

Obviously one can do it with more than one file at a time. It's a pain, but TFS ends up with the right change, and Resharper takes care of changing references.

Answer (score 4):

"tf rename" will tell TFS the file has moved.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a79bz90w.aspx

If you are in VS and move a file from one folder to another, you can see TFS pends a rename. You can also move a file from one folder to another, and then rename the file. TFS pends a rename.

Apparently when resharper is moving files around it is not using move and rename apis in the VS project system, or I would expect this to "just work".

Comment: Move a file between *projects* in VS. It actually does a delete/add not a move. Therefore, I imagine this is actually a VS bug.